# Could not build OpenCV Android sample project

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to build the OpenCV Android sample projects. I added the "OpenCV Library - 2.4.8" as a project to eclipse and trying to build "OpenCV Sample - 15 Puzzle" sample project. When I build the lsample project It gives me the following error.

```
make: *** Android NDK: Aborting...
```

It prints the following in the console.

```
**** Clean-only build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - 15 puzzle ****

D:\ProgramFiles\android-ndk-r9c\ndk-build.cmd clean 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 14 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
D:/ProgramFiles/android-ndk-r9c/build/core/add-application.mk:187: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk
```

In the imported sample project I do not have a Android.mk file. Do I have to include such a file in this sample project? Could somebody please help me to fix this issue? I'm using Windows 8, Eclipse Juno provided in ADT bundle and these are the OpenCV 2.4.8 sample projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` file. Refer to `tutorial-2-mixedprocessing` which comes along with the samples.

I would suggest starting from the easiest sample code, ie, tutorial1.

The details of files that are to be compiled are present in Android.mk

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I again extracted a fresh copy of the OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk and import the samples and ticked the "Copy projects into workpace" and followed this youtube tutorial. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsgY3zcR4bU This solved my issue. Thanks.